# Measure extension on [0,1]

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose $I=[0,1]$, and $\mu$ is a measure s.t

$\mu(A)=0$ and $\mu(I\setminus A)=1$ for every Borel set $A$ of first category. Show that $\mu$ can not be extended to a measure on the Boreal $\sigma$ algebra.

A hint given by the question is using following fact. If $\mu$ is a finite measure defined on the Borel $\sigma$ algebra on $[0,1]$ and $\mu(\{p\})=0$ for every singleton set. Then for every $\epsilon>0$, there is an open interval $J$ containing $p$ with $\mu(J)<\epsilon$.

Comment: What is "of first category"?

Comment: @Brenton Also called [meagre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: construct a nowhere-dense closed set of positive measure by removing a small interval from every open interval.

Comment: Some kind like Cantor set?

Comment: Could you please explain it? I know we can construct a Cantor like set with positive Lebesgue measure. But how can we deal with this situation, the measure can be arbitrary.

Comment: I think I get it, thank you.